# Add Hash methods only for class and its subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class

If what I want is to add method "ok?" into hash but only apply to class C1 and it's sub-class. How to make it?
for example

```
class C1
 class Hash
   def ok?
      return 'nested hash ok'
   end
  end
 def m1
    return Hash.new.ok?  #works
 end
 def m2
    return {}.ok? #not works
 end
end


<<In other file>>
class C2 < C1
 def m1_1
    return {}.ok?   #not works
 end
end
```

How to add '{}.ok?' just in C1 & it's sub-class C2 without module required in each file, but some-way like inhirt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't add a new method to `::Hash`

```
class C1
  class Hash
    def ok?
      return 'nested hash ok'
    end
  end
end
```

It creates a new class `C1::Hash` which has nothing to do with `Hash`. If you want to monkey patch `::Hash` but not on a global scope, have a look at this:
http://yehudakatz.com/2010/11/30/ruby-2-0-refinements-in-practice/

However, this is only available in ruby 2.0.0.